# PHP - Searching through arrays and storing values

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I am having trouble with something. I am pulling playlist item's data from Youtube and using the song title to organize the playlist into specific artist array's.

This is what the arrays are like

```
$playlistMaster = array (
    'foo fighters' => array(),
    'queens of the stone age' => array(),
    ...
    ...
    'misc' => array()
)
```

and this is the code I am dealing with for storing to the arrays

```
//For each playlist item
    foreach($playlist->items AS $item):
        // Stores the song title in a var and makes it lowercase
        $str = $item->snippet->title;
        $str = strtolower($str);

        // Stores the last key of the array
        $last = end($playlistMaster);

        // Takes the first key of the array and checks to see if the song title matches the key name
        $keyString = key($playlistMaster);
        $pos = strpos($str, $keyString);

        // If it is not a match, then move on to the next key, if it reaches the end of the arrays then store that song in the last array.
        if ($pos === false) {
            next($playlistMaster);

            if (next($playlistMaster) === $last) {
                $songId = $item->snippet->title;
                array_push($playlistMaster[$keyString], $songId);
                reset($playlistMaster);
            }                   

            $keyString = key($playlistMaster);
            $pos = strpos($str, $keyString);
        }

        // Else if it is a match then store that song in the current array.
        else {
            $songId = $item->snippet->title;
            array_push($playlistMaster[$keyString], $songId);
            reset($playlistMaster);
        }
    endforeach;
```

Hopefully, Does this makes some kind of sense? I am currently getting no errors but nothing stored to any of the arrays and haven't been able to find a way to 'step-through' PHP like I would with Java to find out what is going on at each step so am getting a bit frustrated with no feedback to go on.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the structure of $playlist array ?

Comment: I wrote out some of the array at the top of my post.
Thanks

Comment: That is $playlistMaster array?

Comment: Oh yes. So  $playlist is from the Youtube API call. I havent had any trouble retrieving data from that array.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, this might achieve your requirement.

```
<?php

$playlistMaster = array (
    'foo fighters' => array('aaa'),
    'queens of the stone age' => array('bbb'),
    'misc' => array('ccc')
);

$playlist = array('ar' => 'ddd','misc' => 'eee');
//For each playlist item
//key is author and value is title/song
    foreach($playlist AS $key=>$val) {
        if(isset($playlistMaster[$key])) {
            if(!in_array($val,$playlistMaster[$key])) {
                array_push($playlistMaster[$key],$val);
            }
        } else {
            $playlistMaster[$key] = array($val);
        }
    }
echo '<pre>';
print_r($playlistMaster);
print_r($playlist);
```